# Как реализуется свет в играх?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

В ютубе полно роликов о том как создать свет в unity, но мне хотелось бы разобраться как его сделать в sfml, то есть на низком уровне, возможно ли вообще сделать динамическое освещение в sfml c++ и на подобных фреймворках или же для этого нужно спуститься до OpenGL?

Речь идет о 2D игре

Comment: это сложная тема, что вы понимаете под "светом", освещение, освещение+затенение (отброс теней), видимость луча света (volumetric light) это все в целом разные техники и алгоритмы

Comment: но в любом случае это все шейдеры...

Comment: ах да, забыл добавить, это 2D проект, и освещение здесь это просто высветление неких участков в тени, но как это сделать я не представляю

Comment: на этой странице все интерактивное - https://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/

Comment: sfml - это не фреймворк, а обертка для мультимедийных API. И предполагает использование opengl для графики. Свет для 2д игры с видом сверху можно сделать через рисование источников света на световой текстуре в градациях серого, которая будет определять уровень освещенности пикселя.

Comment: Хороший вопрос, открой книжку и узнай, потом нам расскажешь =)

Comment: @VengeanceOftheghosts, к сожалению ваш вопрос слишком объёмный и на него крайне сложно ответить в рамках SO. Я сейчас глянул свои записи по освещению - у меня лекция + конспект + дополнительные материалы примерно на 200 страниц (там конечно общий случай для 3д, но в 2д просто на одно изменеи меньше).Я могу вам посоветовать оттолкнуться и изучить сначала модель освещения по Phong и модель освещения по Blinn-Phong (это фамилии двух различных человек, если что, даю на английском, т.к.сам учил на английском и немецком).Ещё посмотрите освещение Halfway-Vektor, Reflexionsvektor R и затухание света.

Comment: @SergeiZhilinski, это даже годится за ответ ведь...

Comment: @SergeiZhilinski да, спасибо, думаю ответ получен

Comment: @Egorithm, кмк нет - у меня нет чёткого ответа хотя бы с какого источника начать изучение, только вектор тем, которые придётся глянуть (причём не всех). У меня даже нет хотя бы грубой реализации одной из систем освещения на плюсах (собственно я сам когда изучал подходы делал всё на WebGl и Javascript). У меня лишь пояснение, почему на такой вопрос крайне сложно ответить в рамках одного ответа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я решил немного расширить свой комментарий, чтобы он тянул на ответ и оформить ответ к данному вопросу, т.к. тема не очень освещена в рунете.
К сожалению ваш вопрос слишком объёмный и на него крайне сложно ответить в рамках SO. Но я могу вам дать список того, с чего стоит начать рассмотрение данной темы:

1. Для начала стоит разобраться с теоретическими азами, что такое свет, какой свет бывает и тд. Начать можно вот с этой [статьи](https://habr.com/ru/company/playgendary/blog/471806/) на хабре (вам нужны первые три раздела).
2. Вам необходимо разобраться с тем, каким функциям подвержен свет (отражение, преломление, рассеивание итд). Емнип это есть в статье выше.

Освещение в компьютерной графике симулирует взаимодействие света и объектов. Рассчёт освещения - симулирует всеразличные законы физики, связанные с освещением, и распространение света в пространстве. Освещение зависит от перспективы камеры (т.е. наблюдателя), материала объекта и окружающей среды (воздух, туман, вода итд).
Для аппроксимации используют нормали к поверхности объекта. В качестве выходной функии любой модели вы получаете интенсивность света (это вектор, направленный от точки прямо в камеру).
На рисунке ниже:
L - источник света
P - точка на поверхности
N - Нормаль
R - отражённый вектор
I - Интенсивность света
[image: Модель освещения. B. T. Phong: Illumination for Computer Generated Pictures. Communications of the ACM 18(6), 1975]

Для окружающего освещения вам потребуется формула

I = I_a * K_a
Где
I_a - интенсивность окружения, константа, вектор формата  (I_aR, I_aG, I_aB)
K_a - Коэффициент отражения объекта, находится в диапазоне от 0 до 1

Обязательно рассмотрите Закон Ламберта, это необходимо для вычисления диффузного отражения для направления света и нормали

И рассмотрите зеркальное отражение.
В итоге у нас получается форумла из 3х компонент для интенсивности света (если я правильно помню, это и есть модель по Понгу):
[image: Уравнение освещенности]

3. После этого разберите такое понятие как затухание света и самые популярные модели освещения: по [Понгу](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model) (Phong) и [Блинну-Понгу](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_reflection_model) (Blinn-Phong). Обязательно рассмотрите Halfway-Vektor для зеркального отражения света, тоже потребуется для второй модели. По поводу второй модели - [вот хороший источник](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/Illumination/Tut11%20BlinnPhong%20Model.html) и [пример на Web-Gl](https://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/%7Ethormae/lectures/graphics1/code/WebGLShaderLightMat/ShaderLightMat.html).

UPD и совсем забыл упомянуть про самую примитивную реализацию света: накладываем поверх всей картинки тёмный фильтр, который выключаем лишь в районе источников света (а там уже делаем один из трёх источников света, которые нам подходят. Про источники света - в первой ссылке).